# See if field is mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to detect if a certain field of a given class has been mapped?

E.G.

I have the object;

```
MyObject {
   private MyOtherObject other
}
```

And in the mapping file;

```
<many-to-one name="other" class="com.mypackage.MyOtherObject" lazy="false" />
```

Now is it possible to detect in java, if other has been mapped? I know I can create a static class containing mapped fields etc. But I'd rather detect it on the fly. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean if it's been loaded into the object, or if Hibernate has correctly configured the mapping?

Comment: Both of those can do, as long as I can see Hibernate has it mapped for MyObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see if the MyOtherObject is mapped, you can try to get the ClassMetadata from the SessionFactory for that class. If it's null, it's not mapped:

```
s.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Bar.class);
```

Comment: Is it possible to see if it is mapped to MyObject?

Comment: With a ClassMetadata object, you can ask Hibernate to return all mapped types, and then you can check if "other" is in the list of mapped types. For that, use the method getPropertyTypes() from ClassMetadata.

Comment: By the way, you can find the javadoc for the ClassMetadata here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html

Comment: And is there a way to see that 'other' has a many-to-one relationship?

Comment: If "other" has a many to one relationship, then the Type class is ManyToOneType . ie, check if Type is in the list of the getPropertyTypes and check if it's an instance of ManyToOneType

Answer (score 0):

use annotations instead of xml and get annotations on the fly using reflection.

Comment: I am not a fan of annotations, and it is not possible to apply to this project.